# Is there a 64bit version of U-Boot's uImage header structure?

Tags: c, u-boot

The U-Boot header file `image.h` defines the header structure of `uImage`. I noticed that the address fields (load and entry address) of the uImage header are defined as `uint32` type.

Is this definition a limitation for the use of `uImage` on 64-bit platforms? Is there a 64-bit version of the `uImage` header structure?

Comment: Maybe a naive question, but does u-boot even run in 64-bit mode? My understanding is that u-boot always runs in 32-bit mode and it's the OS's job to switch to 64-bit mode.